# In a deck of 52 cards, you draw two cards without replacement. Are the events conditionally independent given that the first card drawn is a heart?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, card-games

In a deck of 52 cards, you draw two cards consecutively without replacement. Are the events "drawing a heart on the first draw" and "drawing a black card on the second draw" conditionally independent given that the first card drawn is a heart?

I solved this problem as follows and I would like to know if the approach is correct:

$A: \text{Drawing a heart on the first draw} \\
B: \text{Drawing a black card on the second draw}\\
C: \text{First card drawn is a heart} \\
P(A): \frac{13}{52} = 0.25\\
P(B): \frac{26}{51} \approx 0.5098 \\$

If events $A$ and $B$ are independent then: $P(A\cap B) = P(A)P(B)$.

$P(A\cap B) = \frac{_{13}C_1 \times _{26}C_1}{_{52}C_2} \approx 0.2549\\
P(A)P(B) \approx 0.1275$

Therefore these events are not independent because $P(A)P(B) \neq P(A\cap B)$. Now, we check for conditional independence on $C$.

$P(A|C) = 1$: Because if we know the first card drawn is a heart then it changes the probability of A. Probability of drawing a heart on the first draw given the first draw is a heart is 1.

$P(B|C) = \frac{P(C|B)P(B)}{P(C)}\\
P(C) = P(C|B)P(B) + P(C|B^c)P(B^c) = P(C\cap B) + P(C \cap B^c) = \frac{_{13}C_1 \times _{26}C_1}{_{52}C_2} + \frac{_{13}C_1 \times _{25}C_1}{_{52}C_2} \approx 0.2549 + 0.2451 \approx 0.50\\
P(B|C) = \frac{0.2549}{0.50} \approx 0.5098 \\
P(A \cap B | C) = P(A|C)P(B|C) = 1 \times 0.5098 = 0.5098\text{ must hold for conditional independence.}\\
P(A \cap B|C) = \frac{P(C|A \cap B)P(A \cap B)}{P(C)} = \frac{P(A \cap B \cap C)}{P(C)} = P(A \cap B) = 0.2549.$

Therefore, these events are not independent and, not conditionally independent since, $P(A \cap B|C) \neq P(A|C)P(B|C).$

**Is this approach correct. Are there gaps in my understanding that jump out to you? Is there a better way to solve this question?**

Comment: "$\frac{P(A \cap B \cap C)}{P(C)} = P(A \cap B)$". How did you get to this equality?

Comment: $P(C)$ is in both the numerator and the denominator. $P(A \cap B)P(C) = P(A \cap B \cap C)$. Is the numerator.

Comment: $P(C)$ is not in the numerator unless you are implying $C$ and $A\cap B$ are independent.

Comment: What would be the correct approach then? $C$ and $A \cap B$ are not independent.

Comment: Conditional on $C$, $A$ is a probability 1 event, probability 1 events are independent to all other events. Another approach is to notice $A\cap C \cap B=B\cap C$.

Comment: You wrongly computed both $P(A\cap B$) and $P(A)\cdot P(B)$.

Comment: @user Not to be rude but stating that something is wrong is not enough. Could you at least share the correct approach?

Comment: The correct values are $P(A\cap B)=\frac{13}{52}\frac{26}{51}$ and $P(A)\cdot P(B)=\frac{13}{52}\frac{26}{52}=\frac18$.

Comment: @user Why would you use $\frac{26}{52}$ when calculating $P(B)$. That is the event that the second draw of card is black. This is without replacement. This to me says that there is one card already out of the deck. Should it not remain 26/51?

Comment: @iamlearningmath  All 52 cards have an equal chance of being on the second draw, and 26 among them are black.  So $\mathsf P(B)=26/52$ .

Comment: @iamlearningmath  However, when *given that that the first card is a heart*, then there will be one less card available for the second draw, so:  $\mathsf P(B\mid C)= 26/51$

Comment: Think about the probability of the event $D=$"the second card is red",  provided no knowledge about the first card.

Comment: @GrahamKemp what’s throwing me off here is the fact event $B$ is drawing of the SECOND CARD.  I am having a hard time understanding that if we are being told that this is the second card out of the deck, without replacement, that makes me believe that there were 51 cards in the deck at the time second card was taken out. They all have equal chance of withdrawal, but not out of 52, out of 51.

Comment: @iamlearningmath  There are 51 in the deck and 1 removed.  When it is not given *which* is the removed card, then each of the **52** cards have the same chance to be the second card.

Comment: @GrahamKemp okay, that actually is starting to make sense. Thanks for your patience. Probability really messes with my head, it can be very counterintuitive.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the issues:

- $A$ and $C$ are the same events so, conditioned on $C$, *every event* is independent of $A$, including $B$:  $P(A \cap B \mid C)= P(B \mid C) =P(A \mid C)P(B \mid C)$
- $P(A \cap B) = \frac{13 \times 26}{52 \times 51}$ which is half what you say
- $P(A)P(B)=\frac{13}{52}\times \frac{26}{52}$, close to but not equal to what you say
- $P(B \mid C) = \frac{26}{51}$ as you correctly say but $P(A \cap B \mid C)$ is the same as this rather than half of it.

You can say there is not (unconditional) independence between $A$ and $B$ because $\frac{13 \times 26}{52 \times 51} \approx 0.12745$ is not the same as $\frac{13}{52}\times \frac{26}{52}=0.125$, but this is not the calculation you did.

Intuitively, drawing a heart first makes it more likely the second card is black than not knowing the first card would (you have changed your knowledge about the red cards remaining), so you would not expect independence.

Conditioned on the first card being a heart, drawing a heart on the  first draw would be inevitable so trivially everything else would be independent of that.

Comment: The question was if $A $ and $B $ are *conditionally* independent.

Comment: @user Possibly, but since $A$ and $C$ are the same event, that is the least interesting thing here.  I have edited to clarify  that there is trivial  conditional independence.